# PHP - "more that zero" in if condition

Tags: php, coding-style, code-standards

Often in php i see code lines like

```
if(count($arr)) // $arr not empty
```

or

```
if(!$var) // $var is 0
```

But for me more informative is style like

```
if(count($arr) > 0) // or if(!empty($arr))
```

or

```
if($var == 0)
```

Which do same checking. What option is more correct?
It's not a problem, but just code-style question. Maybe exists some standard(like PSR-2) for conditions like these.

Comment: if(count($arr) > 0)

Answer (score 0):

The first statement is for counting as it says `count()`. This can be array values for example.

```
<?php
$array = array("x", "x", "x");
# Output: 3
echo count($array);
?>
```

The second statement is for checking if the variable `$var` is true or not. You can translate this line as **if $var is not true, then..**

```
<?php
$array = array("x", "x", "x");
if(!$array) {
    echo "True";

}else{

    echo "Does nothing..";
}
?>
```

The third statement is for checking if the counting for `$var` is greater than zero.

```
<?php
# Output: "Is not empty!"
$array = array("x", "x", "x");
if(count($array) > 0)
    echo "Is not empty!";

}else{

    echo "Empty..";
}
?>
```

And the last one is for checking if `$var` is equal to zero.

```
<?php
# Output: "Does nothing.."
$array = array("x", "x", "x");
if($array == 0) {
    echo "Is not empty!";

}else{

    echo "Does nothing..";
}
?>
```

So basically all these four statements have different meanings. As answer to your question would `if(count($arr) > 0)` be the best solution to check if the array has more then zero entries.